# How do you handle authorization and authentication i Microservices?

Tags: authentication, authorization, microservices, openid-connect, keycloak

At my company, we are building an application on top of microservices. We are struggling with deciding how to handle authorization and authentication. We are thinking of going down the path where we use OpenId Connect to authenticate the users, but when it comes to authorization, we need some advice.

Let me explain how to solution works: A user can have different roles in different departments, and the number of departments can exceed 200. In each department, the user can have multiple roles. We understand that the recommended way of handling roles is to put them in the token sent from the client to the server (JWT). But, we are worried that this will make the token payload too big. As far as I know, a browser can hold headers up to 5KB of data. In our case, this means around 50 departments with two roles (uncompressed).  The pros of doing it this way are that the user is authorized and authenticated when he/she enters the microservice. The cons are, as I mentioned, the large payload in the token.

We are also looking at a different option where we keep the JWT to a minimum (userid and departmentid) and query Keycloak for the user rights on every request (maybe add some caching mechanism with a short lifespan). This approach will generate a lot of request to the authorization server.

What I'm looking for is some advice/experience of how others have solved this. I'm happy to provide more information if needed.

To make it easier for you to give your advice, here are a short description of the two choices:
1) Use JWT to handle authentication and authorization? Why?
2) Keep JWT light and make requests to the authorization server in every microservice? Why?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, two options:

### Option 1

1. Keep the JWT light
2. Use OAuth2 "Authorization Code" grant type with both refresh token and access token
3. Cache the user rights in a centralized distributed caching system with an eviction policy like LFU
4. During access token renewal (which will happen periodically depending on the access token validity period), get the latest access rights of the user and refresh the cache
5. If access rights are not available in cache, query the Keycloak and add the entries in the cache

Thus,

1. Any change in rights will take the token validity period to get reflected
2. The performance will be better due to caching

### Option 2

Same as Option 1 except that you can use change data capture (CDC) on the user privilege DB to keep the cache updated with any change in access rights.